# How do I move a character from a position in the string to the very front of it without deleting any character?

Tags: c++, string

My string is about 14 characters long and I have to move a character from somewhere in the string to the very front and I can not delete the character that already sits in `myString[0]`. How do I do it?

Comment: Are you using `std::string`?

Comment: What do you want to do with `myString[0]`? If you start with "apple" and want to move the 'l', do you want to end with "lappe"? Or "lppae"? Or something else?

Comment: yeah, I am using std::string....if my string is apple and I have to move L, it should look like this......lappe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string x = "foobar";
x.insert(0, 1, x[3]); // insert the 4th character at the beginning
x.erase(4, 1);  // erase the 5th character 
                // (5th because the preceding operation added a character
```

See the respective member functions of [basic_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: @MokammelSanju I actually prefer the solution be Blastfurnace.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using `std::string` functions, you could try functions from `<algorithm>`.

```
std::string x = "foobar";
std::rotate(x.begin(), x.begin() + 3, x.begin() + 4); // foobar -> bfooar
```

or:

```
std::reverse(x.begin(), x.begin() + 3); // foobar -> oofbar
std::reverse(x.begin(), x.begin() + 4); // oofbar -> bfooar
```

Neither of these change the string's `size()` and shouldn't trigger a memory reallocation.

Comment: Much better than mine with the convoluted string member functions. I always forget about `rotate`.